Nested Json invocation
I have a jq script like this:
jq -s 'add' \
    < ./tmp/dispatch_03494ecb-9f72-3233-b4dc-173aa725dc24.json \
    < ./tmp/dispatch_03494ecb-9f72-3233-b4dc-173aa725dc24_acknowledgement.json | \
    jq '{ 
        success: .result == "ok", 
        event_type, 
        start_time, 
        end_time 
    }'

and I have a file: $SUCCESS_FILE containing a bunch of base json  files, ie:
./tmp/dispatch_03494ecb-9f72-3233-b4dc-173aa725dc24.json

Which I can tranform to get an array of the path to both the base file and the ack file, ie use this:
jq -Rn '
    [inputs] |
    map({
        base_file: .,
        ack_file: (.[:-5] + "_acknowledgement.json")
    })' < "$SUCCESS_FILE" | jq '.'

to get
[
  {
    "base_file": "tmp/dispatch_03494ecb-9f72-3233-b4dc-173aa725dc24.json"
    "ack_file": "tmp/dispatch_03494ecb-9f72-3233-b4dc-173aa725dc24_acknowledgement.json"
  },
]

I want to combine the two scripts so that for each element of the said array I do a jq invocation with the values of the keys: {base_file, ack_file}
ie, in FP lingo, I want to flatmap the jq invocation demonstrated earlier to the elements of the array as constructed by the latter jq invocation. Have no idea how though.
If this is not possible via jq alone, how can I do this in the shell layer? ideally in zsh

jq can only read the contents of named files if the filenames are provided on the command line,
so your construction of '{base_file, ack_file}' objects won't help.
However I believe your approach can be made to work by using the bash while read idiom
along the following lines:
cat "$SUCCESS_FILE" |
 jq -R '.,  (.[:-5] + "_acknowledgement.json")' |
 while read base_file ack_file ; do jq -s add "$base_file" "$ack_file" |
     jq '.'
 done

where '.' in the last-most invocation of jq above is just a place-holder
for your main program.

BTW, in future, it would probably be a good idea to adhere more closely
to the MCVE guidelines.

I don't know jq well enough, but couldn't process substitiution work, i.e. using <(jq ..... ) in place of the filename? In this case, zsh would create a named pipe and pass to the "outer" jq the name of the pipe.
